# What happens to a byte array in C# when passed to unmanaged code in a struct?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, struct, unmanaged

I'm working on a .NET DLL to access a C++ library that I was given.  In the C++ library, there is this struct:

```
typedef struct FOO
{
    DWORD DataSize;
    BYTE  *pData;
}
```

I've recreated it in C# thus:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FOO
{
    public uint DataSize;
    public byte[] pData;
}
```

My import from the C++ DLL is next.  I'm going to include the header from the C++ side as well.  The method in C++ takes a pointer to the structure I'm passing in, so from what I've been able to gather passing a reference in would work in this case:

```
// C++ Header
HRESULT CallFoo(FOO * pFoo);

[DllImport("SomeLibrary.DLL", EntryPoint = "CallFoo")]
private static extern uint CallFoo(ref FOO rFoo);
```

When I step into my code in the C++ side, I'm getting the structure but the value in pData is a memory address.  This appears to be fouling the code in the C++ library but I can't make sense of the HRESULT it's returning to me (I've put in a question to the owner of the C++ library as to what the error message is).

Another approach I took based upon [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627521/passing-a-struct-with-a-byte-array-inside-to-a-interop-ed-method), was to try passing an IntPtr instead of a byte array.  I modified the struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FOO
{
    public uint DataSize;
    public IntPtr pData;
}
```

and to call it:

```
FOO fooParm = new Foo();
var ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
byte[] bArr = MethodThatReturnsAByteArray();

ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bArr.Length);
Marshal.Copy(bArr, 0, ptr, bArr.Length);

fooParm.pData = ptr;
fooParm.DataSize = bArr.Length;

uint i = CallFoo(fooParm);
```

This unfortunately is not working either.  I get the same error code as the original approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole approach is not good. There is some info on the layout of the managed structs/classes, but it is better not to use it. Try to do this:

```
[DllImport("SomeLibrary.DLL", EntryPoint = "CallFoo")]
private static extern uint CallFoo(uint DataSize, IntPtr pData);
```

The more simple parameters you pass back and forth, the better the result will be.

Comment: I would love to not use these custom structures but unfortunately the library is not something I have control over.  I have written a managed C++ wrapper for it that I possibly could handle the translation in before making the library call, I will take a look at that approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the C++ library in front of me, so it's hard to answer this question accurately, I feel, but it sounds like you're getting a pointer and the library is having problems with that. Would it be possible to use `Marshal::PtrToStructure` to map that `byte[]` pointer to a proper `struct`?

Here is a link to the particular method that I'm talking about. The second code example near bottom (in C++) might apply: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx

Comment: I will take a closer look at this tonight when I get off work.  Another approach I had tried that I failed to mention was passing the entire struct as an IntPtr, maybe I need to revisit that approach again.