# Call a function in a c++ dll from c#

Tags: c#

I want call a Function in a c++ dll from c# but i can't get it work.
That is the Dokumentation from the Function :

> VOID WINAPI EnumerateHidDevices( PVOID pContext, ENUM_HID_PROC Callback);
>
> **Function description:**
>   Enumerates all of the EETI PCAP HID touch devices in the system.
>
> ***Parameters:***
>
> **pContext**:The pointer point to caller prepared memory. This address will be passed to the callback routine.
>
> **Callback**:Caller prepared callback routine. This callback routine will be called whenever the API enumerates a PCAP touch device.
>
> **ENUM_HID_PROC**:Prototype of device enumeration callback routine.
>
> typedef BOOL (WINAPI *ENUM_HID_PROC)(PVOID pContext,LPCTSTR  szSymbolicName, LPCTSTR szProduct, ULONG ulInLength, ULONG ulOutLength);
>
> **pContext**:Pointer to the caller prepared buffer for the callback routine.
>
> **szSymbolicName**:The device symbolic Link Name the device enumerator enumerated. This string need be used to open the device with OpenHIDDevice.
>
> **szProduct**:Identifies product name
>
> **ulInLength**:Maximum size of input report in bytes. This parameter need be used to open the device with OpenHIDDevice.
>
> **ulOutLength**:
>   Maximum size of output report in bytes. This parameter need be used to open the device with OpenHIDDevice.

And that how its look at the moment in c#:

```
    public HID_DEVICE_INFO m_HIDDevInfo = new HID_DEVICE_INFO();
    public struct HID_DEVICE_INFO
    {
        public string strDeviceName;
        public uint m_ulInLength;
        public uint m_ulOutLength;
        public ushort m_VID;
        public ushort m_PID;
    }

    public delegate int ENUM_HID_PROC(object pContext, string szSymbolicName, string szProduct, uint ulInLength, uint ulOutLength);

    [DllImport("HIDdAPI.dll")]
    public static extern void EnumerateHidDevices(object pContext, ENUM_HID_PROC Callback);

    public MainView1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        EnumerateHidDevices(m_HIDDevInfo, EnumUsbHidCallback);
    }

    public static int EnumUsbHidCallback(object pContext, string szDeviceName, string szProduct, uint ulInLength, uint ulOutLength)
    {
        HID_DEVICE_INFO pInfo = (HID_DEVICE_INFO)pContext;

        pInfo.strDeviceName = szDeviceName;
        Console.Write("\r\n");
        Console.Write("Enumerate EETI HID Device: {0}\r\n", pInfo.strDeviceName);
        Console.Write("\r\n");
        pInfo.m_ulInLength = ulInLength;
        pInfo.m_ulOutLength = ulOutLength;

        return 1;
    }
```

This ends in an ArgumentException at EnumerateHidDevices(m_HIDDevInfo, EnumUsbHidCallback):

> System.ArgumentException occurred
>
> HResult=-2147024809
>
> Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
>
> Source=mscorlib
>
> StackTrace:
>          at System.StubHelpers.ObjectMarshaler.ConvertToNative(Object objSrc, IntPtr pDstVariant)
>     InnerException:

Where is the problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: default values for public HID_DEVICE_INFO m_HIDDevInfo = new HID_DEVICE_INFO();

Comment: Hi Jack, I has added default values, but still the same ArgumentException at EnumerateHidDevices(m_HIDDevInfo, EnumUsbHidCallback);

Comment: I don't see you setting a calling convention

Comment: Hi Krzystof, tried already with a calling convention, nothing changed at all

Comment: Can you just clarify on which line you are getting the exception, and also interrogate whether there is anything of use within the argument exception, e.g. ParamName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho your code is unsafe. I can't see you pinning your object anywhere in your snippet. I believe the correct way to do what you want is to pass [`IntPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the method and get a pointer to `struct` via [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx).

You may also want to check [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627521/passing-a-struct-with-a-byte-array-inside-to-a-interop-ed-method)